# Cannot remove directory from command line

Tags: shell, command-line, command, command-line-interface

I must be doing something wrong. I am trying to delete the 'mounts' directory and all its contents. Any ideas??

```
dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ ls 
lib/  mounts/  workspace/

dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ rm -rf mounts
rm: cannot remove ‘mounts/deanfriedlandcom2’: Is a directory

dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ umount mounts/deanfriedlandcom2
umount: /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2 is not in the fstab (and you are not root)
```

Comment: I remember such a weird error output but I can not recall the solution. Can you post the permissions: `find mounts \! -user dfmmalaw -print`

Comment: It's not related whether there are mounted directories below or not, but if you want to unmount a directory with `umount`, you should be `root` (by `su` or `sudo umount`)

Comment: dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ find mounts \! -user dfmmalaw -print
     find: `dfmmalaw' is not the name of a known user

Comment: dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ sudo umount mounts
         umount: mounts: must be superuser to umount

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2 is not in the fstab` show the result of `grep deanfriedlandcom2 /etc/mtab` (or just type `mount` alone and see if `deanfriedlandcom2` is listed as mounted.)

Comment: try replacing with appropriate username: `find mounts \! -user $(whoami) -print`

Comment: deanmpcv@server173.web-hosting.com:public_html /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2 fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0

Comment: @DeanFriedland `sudo umount mounts umount: mounts: must be superuser ...` You do not have sudo rights apparently. So `su` (then type root password) then try `umount` again. (`user_id=0,group_id=0` - confirms the mount by root)

Comment: @ David. Strange, I am getting the following error... su: Authentication failure

Comment: `dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~ $ id`                   
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),27(sudo),1001(rvm)

Comment: `sudo` is spelled with 4 characters; `su` is spelled with 2.  If you use `su`, you need to provide root's password; if you use `sudo`, you need to provide your own password.  Even without root privileges, you may be able to run the `mount` command with no arguments to get a list of mounted file systems (but the command might be in `/sbin` or perhaps `/usr/sbin` rather than `/bin` or `/usr/bin` — you might need to check your PATH if simply typing `mount` comes up with command not found).

Comment: No; there isn't a way to find the root password; either you know it, or you know someone who knows it, or you're snookered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*look for your mount record in the results of the mount command below, it will contain /deanfriedlandcom2 in your case.*

Example record: **/home/dfmmalaw/downloads/camera_software.iso on /deanfriedlandcom2 type iso9660 (ro)**

```
sudo su
cd /home/ubuntu/
mount 
umount /home/ubuntu/downloads/camera_software.iso mounts/deanfriedlandcom2 #umount <filesystem> <mount point>
rm -rfd mounts
```

Comment: Sorry but what goes here? `umount /dev/hda2_example /dir2_example` #umount <filesystem> <mount point>`

Comment: I am now here `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu# `

Comment: Got it. --->>>> `deanmpcv@server173.web-hosting.com:public_html on /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2`

Comment: No luck  :(                                                                                                                    `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu# sudo umount /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2` returns
                                                                                                           `umount: /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2: must be superuser to umount`

Comment: Saw your edit. Unfortunately  `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu# umount /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2`  returns  
`umount: /home/ubuntu/mounts/deanfriedlandcom2: must be superuser to umount`

Comment: Well then your root user is not a super user which is very odd. And from the feedback display `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382` I can see that you are definitely root. I think you should speak to the device administrator unless you are the owner then you have some trail and error to attend to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mount point is unmounted and then remove the directory:

Using `sudo`:

```
sudo umount mounts

sudo rm -rf mounts
```

Or one can use `su`:

user@host $ su

user@host # umount mounts

user@host # rm -rf mounts

Comment: what can I do from here I am now here? `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu#`

Comment: `root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu# sudo umount mounts
umount: mounts: must be superuser to umount`

Comment: Better question, how do I get back to `dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~` ???? At least then I can try your suggestion

Comment: Try just  umount mounts  from root@dfmmalaw-portfolio-php--1881382:/home/ubuntu#

Comment: `umount mounts` returns `umount: mounts: must be superuser to umount`

Comment: Should I go back to `dfmmalaw@portfolio-php-:~` ?